# disable word online and excel online for SharePoint site where I don't have admin access

Tags: 2013, document-library, excel, word

I have read access to numerous document libraries on numerous SharePoint sites. When I click on a Word or Excel document it opens in Word Online or Excel Online.

I want to make it so the browser either asks me to download the file or it straight opens in Word/Excel.

All the articles I have read online talk about making changes to the site or document library settings but only an admin can make those changes and they apply to all users.

Is there anyway I can set my personal settings so they override the site/document library settings and always open how I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way for you to modify these settings without having at least Edit access to the Library or Owner access to the Site.